# Non-English Font

Tags: fonts

After changing keyboard layout by `setxkbmap`,If I typing something in an GUI apps, then it results in blank squares or dotted circle.

Is there anything I am missing in LFS OS

Comment: Changes made to tags

Comment: You might also be missing an X font server that can make sense of Unicode or ttf/otf, but I know nothing about the configuration of LFS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a font covering most glyphs of every language, there probably is none.

Here are two fonts that have quite a large coverage: [Arial Unicode MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS) and [Everson Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everson_Mono).

Comment: Question rephrased !   :-/

Comment: Does the font you use for your GUI contain the letter you tried to input? Did you try changing to a font covering the particular range you want to display?

Comment: GUI is any standard application. e.g. leafpad   I don't know, which font I need to set for proper display. If I do not change the font then what I see is dotted circle or blank squares

Comment: Select a font which supports the glyphs you want to display. There are two suggestions in my answer. You do know how to change the font, right?

Comment: Only one font will be suffice ?  What are those "ttf" or "pcf" files in standard distribution ? ( Above mentioned font is shareware, so can't use it )

Comment: TTF are TrueType vector fonts and PCF are compiled X11 bitmap fonts.

Comment: https://www.google.com/get/noto/ is Google's attempt to cover all languages with a family of fonts, but there's dozens of fonts to complete the set.

Answer (score 0):

The [Liberation font-family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts) was specifically designed to cover most latinate (US, EU, Cyrillic, Greek) Unicode code points and are available in most major distributions.

They don't cover Asian, Semetic, Native American typefaces, or Klingon, but I think you would have made mention if you needed those.

(My apologies if people in the Americas take exception to being lumped in with US or EU, but I'm talking typography not politics, and I don't know a more general term).